# Execute compiled groovy script from java via reflection

Tags: java, groovy, reflection

I have many groovy scripts which are compiled with GMaven (located in `src/main/groovy/somepackage`), each script has `run(String, String)` function and does not have a class:

```
// script1.groovy
def run(String name, String arg) {
  // body
}


// script2.groovy
def run(String name, String arg) {
  // body
}
```

I can find them with Reflections library and resolve their types:

```
final Set<String> scripts = new Reflections(
  "somepackage",
   new SubTypesScanner(false)
).getAllTypes();
for (String script : scripts) {
  run(Class.forName(name));
}
```

then I have some issues with execution: I can't create scipt instance because it doesn't have public constructor (has only private one with `groovy.lang.Reference` parameters) and I can't find `run` method in this type.

The question: how to execute compiled groovy script (with single method and without a class) from Java using reflection properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load compiled Groovy scripts from given package using:

```
Reflections.getSubTypesOf(groovy.lang.Script.class)
```

It returns a `Set<Class<? extends Script>>` so you can iterate over those classes, instantiate them and invoke method using `Class.invokeMethod(String name, Object args)`

> **ATTENTION**: you wont be able to call this method like `script.run(string1, string2)`, because this method does not exist in parent `groovy.lang.Script` class.

Below you can find an example:

```
import groovy.lang.Script;
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner;

import java.util.Set;

public class LoadGroovyScriptExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Set<Class<? extends Script>> scripts = new Reflections("somepackage", new SubTypesScanner(false))
                .getSubTypesOf(Script.class);

        for (Class<? extends Script> script : scripts) {
            script.newInstance().invokeMethod("run", new Object[] { "test", "123" });
        }
    }
}
```

*somepackage/script1.groovy*

```
package somepackage

def run(String name, String arg) {
    println "running script1.groovy: ${name}, ${arg}"
}
```

*somepackage/script2.groovy*

```
package somepackage

def run(String name, String arg) {
    println "running script2.groovy: ${name}, ${arg}"
}
```

#### Console output

```
[main] INFO org.reflections.Reflections - Reflections took 93 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 1 keys and 2 values 
running script2.groovy: test, 123
running script1.groovy: test, 123
```